# Error al tratar de recuperar valor en un JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, api

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Android, en el que estoy usando Volley para consumir un Api. La consulta la está realizando correctamente y me retorna el siguiente JSON.

```
[
    {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d5",
        "empresas": "5dfbeec1f87e0e3030b38143",
        "Codigo": "1001AZXL001",
        "Codigo_Barras": "7702345654127",
        "Descripcion": "JEAN talla XL ",
        "Detalles": [
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d7",
                "bodegas": "5dfd2383971f730f31cc12cf",
                "Cantidad": 6,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d6",
                "bodegas": "5dfd23b7971f730f31cc12d0",
                "Cantidad": 15,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            }
        ],
        "Talla": "XL",
        "Color": "AZ",
        "Minimo": 5000,
        "Maximo": 30000,
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2019-12-20T19:58:51.720Z"
    }
]
```

Pero quiero recuperar los valores contenidos en el detalle **"Detalles"**, precisamente el campo de **bodegas**.

```
"Detalles": [
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d7",
                "bodegas": "5dfd2383971f730f31cc12cf",
                "Cantidad": 6,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dfd27fb971f730f31cc12d6",
                "bodegas": "5dfd23b7971f730f31cc12d0",
                "Cantidad": 15,
                "Precio": 150000,
                "Unidad_Medida": "UND"
            }
        ]
```

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para recorrer el json y recuperar los valores

```
 public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {

                         for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
                                    tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");
                                    txtDescripcion.setText(descripcionProducto);
                                    txtUnidades.setText(tallaProducto);

                                }
                                catch(JSONException e) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Trate de convertir el Array en un JSONObject pero no funciono, al parecer es un array dentro de un array pero no tengo muy claro como puedo recorrerlo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? En tu código no obtienes nunca el JSONArray  que hay en la clave `Detalles`.

Comment: O sea, algo así: `JSONArray mDetalles= jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detalles");` Y luego tendrías que sacar los JSONObject  que hay dentro de `mDetalles` abriendo un bucle o accediendo directamente por el índice en caso de que te interese sólo un objeto en concreto.

Comment: Me dice que no se puede convertir ese Json en un jsonobject

Comment: Pulsa [edit]  para mostrar el código que estás usando y adjunta también la traza del error.

Comment: @CarlosDnl tienes que obtener el objeto dentro del array principal y después buscar el array "Detalles", es importante revises la estructrura de tu JSON para conocer como obtener los datos,  agregue una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes revisar la estructura para saber como acceder a los elementos, en este caso esta sería la estructura:

```
[  //Array
    { //Objeto            
        "Descripcion": //Elemento dentro del objeto.
         ...
        "Detalles": [ //Array
            {
              //Objeto
            }
            ...
            ]
           "Talla": //Elemento dentro del objeto.
        }
    ]
```

Recuerda siempre que:

> Si inicia con  `[`, significa que es un `JSONArray`
>
> Si inicia con  `{,` significa que es un objeto `JSONObject`.

Por lo tanto, si deseas obtener los valores de "Descripcion" y "Talla", estos se encuentran dentro del objeto del array, por lo tanto para obtenerlos esta sería la forma correcta.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {

                //Revisa el objeto dentro del array
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //Agrega Descripcion y Talla
                descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
                tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");

                 }
       }
```

Si deseas leer los valores : "_id", "bodegas", "Cantidad", "Precio", "Unidad_Medida" , estos se encuentran dentro del objeto contenido dentro del array `"Detalles"`, por lo tanto tienes que buscar dentro de estos objetos.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {

            //Revisa el objeto dentro del array
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //Agrega Descripcion y Talla
            descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
            tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");

            //"Detalles" es un JSONArray
            JSONArray jsonArrayDetalles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detalles");

            //Itera sobre el array "Detalles"
            for(int j = 0; j < jsonArrayDetalles.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println("_id: " + jsonArrayDetalles.getJSONObject(j).optString("_id", ""));
                System.out.println("Bodegas: " + jsonArrayDetalles.getJSONObject(j).optString("Bodegas"));
                System.out.println("Cantidad: " + jsonArrayDetalles.getJSONObject(j).optString("Cantidad"));
                System.out.println("Precio: " + jsonArrayDetalles.getJSONObject(j).optString("Precio"));
                System.out.println("Precio: " + jsonArrayDetalles.getJSONObject(j).optString("Precio"));
            }

        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

- Te sugiero usar el método `optString(Key, default)` para que en caso de no encontrarse el valor, puedas asignar un valor default, en el ejemplo anterior asigna valores de cadena vacios.

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar el valor de bodegas deberías de añadir otro bucle dentro del que ya tienes, tratando el valor de detalles como otro JSONArray y obteniendo sus JSONObject.

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
String descripcionProducto;
JSONObject jsonDetalles;
JSONObject jsonObject;
String tallaProducto;
JSONArray detalles;
String bodegas;

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        tallaProducto = jsonObject.getString("Talla");
        detalles = jsonArray.getJSONObject("Detalles");
        descripcionProducto = jsonObject.getString("Descripcion");
        for (int j = 0; j < detalles.size(); j++) {
            jsonDetalles = detalles.getJSONObject(j);
            bodegas = jsonDetalles.getString("bodegas");
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {

    }
}
```

}